# Is there any site provides a common online information collection and excel export service?

Tags: service

Frequently I need to collect structured information from colleagues and arrange into excel, instead of developping a brand new web-application each time, I was wondering is there exist a site (such as google or other service provider) provides the common online information collection service as follow:

1) Admin input what data need to collect, sample:

Name:

Age:

Address:

2) People logon to the site and populate the record.

3) Records saved into db on server and can be export to Excel(or other data) on anytime for Admin.

As most of the process is similar, I can use the system on-demand for various purposes with just modifying the key of pair.

So can anyone help? Any clue is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use [google spreadsheets](http://docs.google.com) to make a survey. For more information, follow [this link](http://drapestakes.blogspot.com/2008/02/surveys-via-google-spreadsheets.html).

Once respondents fill out your survey, their data will be stored in a spreadsheet, which you can export in a variety of formats, including *.xls* and *.csv*.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thank you very much! :)